# Asp.Net: is it possible to have string resources for different languages in website

Tags: asp.net, translate

i am working on a website which it has world wide users .so i decide to translate content of website.

**The Main problem** is that i have to search all the pages to find text to translate.Therefore , if there is a situation like android studio offers like `string.xml` which concentrates all text, then it can be translated easily.

Like this

```
Website---|
          |Text---|
                  |--->en-us Hello world
                  |--->it    salve verbum
                  |--->ra    привет слово
                  |--->fa    bonjour mot
```

is there a solution?

I am appreciate your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. You have your web.config and inside the

configuration -> configSections

node you can create a languages node, like this:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="languages" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler" allowLocation="false" />
    </configSections>
</configuration>
```

and then, inside the configuration node you can create your languages node, like:

```
<languages>
    <welcome>
        <en>welcome</en>
        <ge>willkommen</ge>
    </welcome>
</languages>
```

Comment: can you bring me an example in asp.net page please?